# Excel VBA - Do not execute if

Tags: vba, excel

This is my Macro for a time stamp:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("N:N"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 6
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

I did not write this originally. I found it off of a forum as my macro knowledge is primitive at best.

Essentially I would like the time stamp to ONLY OCCUR ONCE so I need this macro **not to run if** a time stamp already exists in column AK.

Comment: Where does AK come from? You appear to be offsetting 6 columns from N which isT.

Comment: add something like `if rng.offset(0,xOffsetColumn) <> "" then ` so that the existing time stamp won't be overridden with a new one.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to update the references when I posted it. It should be Range ("A:A") for the cell change and xoffsetcolumn =36 (for column AK).

Comment: Where do I need to add the function you suggested? Also, how do I end it?

Comment: Well you either wrap your procedure with an `If... End If` block with a positive conditional (`if rng.offset(0,xOffsetColumn) = "" then`), or you add a *guard clause* at the beginning with a negative conditional and bail out (`If rng.offset(0,xOffsetColumn) <> "" Then Exit Sub`).

Comment: Ok, so this is what I have going now:

Comment: If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn) <> "" Then

Comment: And added an "End if" before the "End Sub" and it's giving me an error: "Next without For"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want. It checks if AK is blank - if so, it adds the date, if not, it does nothing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Long
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 36

If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            If Len(Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn)) = 0 Then
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
            End If
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO! You just saved my entire spreadsheet. Accept this virtual hug as your thanks (>")>